# How to check for empty item in a generic list

Tags: c#, list, generics

```
Assert.IsTrue(benefits.Count(P => string.IsNullOrEmpty(P.bCode)) > 0);
```

HEre benefits is list of objects of type Obj...which has one property bCode.

I want to check if all items in list benefits has "bCode"...not null and not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
benefits.All(b => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(b.bCode));
```

You can read about [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) on MSDN. Note that it exhibits "short-circuiting" behavior like `&&` (which is what it is analogous to). You can wrap this is in `Assert.IsTrue` if you so desire for your test runner.

You should seriously consider renaming `bCode` to `BenefitCode`, assuming that is what it stands for. There is no reason to not use meaningful business names. Your ORM can handle it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Assert.IsTrue(!benefits.Any(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.bCode)));
```

Comment: I didn't find any difference between `.Any` and `.TrueForAll` here because OP is using a `List<T>`, both +1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
benefits.TrueForAll(P=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(P.bCode))
```

Answer (score 1):

.net 2.0 version:

```
List<Obj> findResults = benefits.FindAll((Predicate<string>)delegate(Obj item)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrempty(item.bCode);
});

return findResults.Count == benefits.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to ensure that no `bCode` property within `benefits` is null or empty?  Does the code you provided not work?  How about this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(benefits.Where(b => string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.bCode)).Count() == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to ensure that each benefits item is not null (which your question does not specify), you can use this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(!benefits.Any(p => p == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.bCode)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Small correct use .Trim()
This will work in ideal situation however in the following case it will not work

> Assert.IsTrue(!benefits.Any(p =>
>   string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.bCode)));

```
        string[] input = new[] {"A", "", "B"," ", "C", "D"};

        int count = input.Count(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(i));

        Console.WriteLine(count); // Result will be 1 now which is incorrect
```

Use

```
        string[] input = new[] {"A", "", "B"," ", "C", "D"};

        int count = input.Count(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Trim()));

        Console.WriteLine(count); // Result will be 2 now which is correct
```

I would suggest to use

Assert.IsTrue(!benefits.Any(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.bCode.Trim()))); // for better result